# How to prefetch SocialAccount with django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, prefetch

Django-allauth package creates a model SocialAccount, with a ForeignKey to User. I can't manage to prefetch this information in my queryset.

My model:

```
class Placerating(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Django-allauth model:

```
class SocialAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth.app_settings.USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I try to prefetch this data:

```
rating = Placerating.objects.all().prefetch_related('author__socialaccount')
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: Cannot find 'socialaccount' on User object, 'author__socialaccount' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

Any clue ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.

SocialAccount is a reverse Foreign key, so "_set" must be added at the end:

rating = Placerating.objects.all().prefetch_related('author__socialaccount_set')